# Using namedQueries with the multi-tenant-single-db plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a domain class lets say

```
class ListItem {
  Long tenantId
}
```

I want to create a namedquery like such

```
active {
   Long currentTenantId = ?????????;
   or {             
      isNull('tenantId')
      eq ('tenantId', currentTenantId);
  }
}
```

In otherwords I want there to be ListItem records what everyone can access and listItem records ONLY the tenant can access.

Browsing the source of the plugin I cannot see how I can find out the current tenant without adding a service ref.

Is this possible?

EDIT: The intention is that currentTentantId is not passed as a parameter. Maybe I am being idealistic.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
active { Long currentTenantId ->
   or {             
      isNull 'tenantId'
      eq 'tenantId', currentTenantId
  }
}
```